# Microsoft azure mobile service key

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

How to put the key? The guide says declare it in Javascript file, but from what I know it will exposes my key to the public.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in your statement that the keys will be exposed to the public and unfortunately there's no way to hide this information.

From [`How to use an HTML/JavaScript client for Azure Mobile Services`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/):

> The application key is intended to filter-out random request against
>   your mobile service, and it is distributed with the application.
>   Because this key is not encrypted, it cannot be considered secure. To
>   truly secure your mobile service data, you must instead authenticate
>   users before allowing access.

Microsoft recommends that you must authenticate your users. To learn more about authenticating users, please see this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/#authentication.

Comment: I see. But imagine u make ur API using mobile service, and it should be call by everyone who use your app. There shouldn't be any login.

Comment: Don't you want to secure your API and ensure that users who are supposed to consume it are consuming it and not everybody else? Can you describe your application scenario in more details (please edit your question for that instead of providing details in the comments).

Comment: That's quite off topic. I think you answered my question above. Says I want to make an app that let people order food for a restaurant. The restaurant owner can edit his latest menu. But for the app users, there's no point he need to login to see the menu.